# 2 claims I have to determine whether they're true or false (improper integrals and infinite series)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

Originally, those are "prove/disprove" questions, in which I should determine whether each claim is correct, if it is, I should prove it. And if its not, I should give a counter example.
I have 2 claims left that I couldnt decide about:

Let $ f:[1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R} $ be a continious function. Then:

If $ \lim_{x\to\infty}f\left(x\right)=L\in\mathbb{R} $ exists, and $ L\neq0 $ then $ \intop_{1}^{\infty}f\left(x\right)\sin xdx $ diverge.

I know this claim is correct. (All of the rest in this question were false). But I cannot prove it in a formal way. I mean, we cannot use comparison's test because we cant say anything about $ f $ that is not negative/positive.  So Im not sure how to show that its correct.

The second claim:

let $ \left(a_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty},\left(b_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty} $ be fixed real sequences.

Which of the following is enough to assume in order for $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}b_{n} $ to be convergent?

Well, I decided for all of the options that appeared, except for one:

$ 0\leq a_{n}\leq\frac{1}{n} $ and  $ b_{n}=\left(-1\right)^{n} $

Im pretty sure that its correct, I want to say that its because

$ 0\leq\left(-1\right)^{n}a_{n}\leq\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n} $ and since $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n} $ then it follow's Cauchy's term, but I think that I'm missing here something. ( I guess I should me more careful with the signs of the inequallity)

I'd appreciate some help with this claims. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the integral refers to Lebesgue integration.

Suppose $L>0$ (the proof is similar if $L<0$). There is an $x_0$ such that $x>x_0\implies f(x)\ge\frac{L}{2}$. So $$\int_{x_0}^N|f(x)\sin x|dx\ge\frac{L}{2}\int_{x_0}^N|\sin x|dx\to \infty\mathrm{\ as\ }N\to\infty.$$

For the second question, the claim is false:

Take $a_n:=\begin{cases}1/n&n\mathrm{\ odd}\\ 0&n\mathrm{\ even}\end{cases}$. Then $$\sum_n(-1)^na_n=1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots\to\infty$$